# How to get current total records of datatable jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable

```
var id = studentDataTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal()
```

I can get total records of datatable. But when i delete a row in datatable using ajax without refresh page, and if i add to data to datatable using ajax, my id increase.

For example : 
My current total data is 50. after i delete two record and add one record, i call the `fnRecordsTotal()` returns 51 not 49.

But if i refresh the page, it returns 49.

Comment: I think you'll have to re-initialize your datatable in the success() method of your ajax call after you make the row changes.

Comment: @gatebasher_311 do i have to get from database whole data again ?

Comment: just something similar to this: $('#myTable').datatable({...});